# Easiest way to migrate existing DNS from 2003 server to 2012R2?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012

I currently have a domain with 5 domain controllers. All running 2003 except for one 2008R2. I'm going to start replacing all the current servers with 2012, doing the FSMO last.

What is the best practice when migrating DNS to the new server? Can I just install DNS, point it to another existing domain controller and let it automatically sync or will I be forced to do it manually?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your zones are AD-Integrated, when you promote the new servers to DCs, they should automatically get the new zones.

Comment: Yep, this is the answer. ADI zones are stored in the directory, so simply promoting new DCs with the DNS role installed will handle this for you automatically.